# Unable to install xdebug - undefined symbol: zend_post_startup_cb

Tags: linux, php, opensuse, xdebug

I uninstalled php7 with `apt-get purge php` and installed it again with `zypper in php7 php7-mysql`.

Then I followed the [install instructions of xdebug](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) and restarted apache with `systemctl restart apache2`, but there is no xdebug in my `phpinfo()`, only some occurences in HTTP_HEADER e.g. (XDEBUG_SESSION=netbeans-xdebug;)

This is my configuration in php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php7/extensions/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="192.168.40.161"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.renite_enable = 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = '/var/log/xdebug'
```

The file `/usr/lib64/php7/extensions/xdebug.so` does exist, I just installed xdebug from source and copied xdebug.so from `modules/xdebug.so` to `/usr/lib64/php7/extensions/`

I even restarted the whole server.

How can I fix this?

**Update:**

I checked the apache2 error log `/var/log/apache2/error_log` and noticed that this is getting logged just right after restarting the apache2 service:

```
[Tue Jul 30 14:25:08.674685 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4862] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
AH00558: httpd-prefork: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.40.44. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Jul 30 14:25:08.758551 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 5060] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php7/extensions/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib64/php7/extensions/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_post_startup_cb
[Tue Jul 30 14:25:08.765786 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5060] AH00163: Apache/2.4.33 (Linux/SUSE) OpenSSL/1.1.0i-fips PHP/7.2.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 30 14:25:08.765815 2019] [core:notice] [pid 5060] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd-prefork -D SYSCONFIG -C PidFile /var/run/httpd.pid -C Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d//loadmodule.conf -C Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d//global.conf -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -c Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d//include.conf -D SYSTEMD -D FOREGROUND'
```

=> `Failed loading /usr/lib64/php7/extensions/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib64/php7/extensions/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_post_startup_cb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to install it by executing `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug`. I wonder why it does not work if I try to install it manually by going the official way and installing it via source...??

However, I get "Waiting for Connection" in NetBeans and nothing happens, but this is another problem...

Answer (score 5):

In my case, since I use php7.2 and there is another PHP version installed on my Ubuntu, so, I have to install the xdebug with the correct version.

I follow the step given from the official site: https://xdebug.org/wizard.

But I have to change some syntax to use the correct PHP version like `phpize` needs to be changed to `phpize-7.2` and use the specific `php-config` version to do the `./configure` step like this:

`./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config7.2`

Reference: http://ubuntuhowtoo.blogspot.com/2020/06/php-xdebug-multi-php-versions-in-server.html

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i just put this xdebug config the wrong file:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

which is /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
, instead, it should be /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 2):

I found this error by trying to install xdebug for php 7.2 on my Fedora, following the official xdebug instructions. I installed that version via remi repository since I have more than one version of php installed. After hours of trying to fix this error, I found that there is an official release of xdebug compatibile with php from remi repository. It can be installed as easily as running this command and it works perfectly.

```
sudo yum install php72-php-xdebug
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.

I was address it with replace **xdebug.ini** file

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.start_with_request="yes"
xdebug.mode="debug"
xdebug.log="/var/www/html/logs/xdebug.log"
xdebug.client_port=9003(your port)
```

The file is located on

```
 /etc/php/7.3{php version file should be
there}/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```